# Profile answers list – large vote count CSS bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, votes, profile-page

There's a CSS rule for `.answer-votes.large` that is applied to answers whose vote total is somewhere above 34. That rule applies a `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` property that ruins the vertical centring of the vote count number (it also applies a `font-size` property, but that one is overridden by a `!important` rule later in the stylesheet).

Removing both padding declarations improves the layout. Here's how it looks right now (in Chrome on OS X):

[image: Screenshot of the current behaviour]

…and here's how it looks with the padding declarations removed:

[image: Screenshot of the behaviour with the padding declarations removed]

Comment: I've tagged this with Design as some of the SE team have a watch out for specific tags and tag combinations ('design' and 'bug' being one of them) and this is sort of a design issue, so hopefully it'll get spotted by someone on the main SE team to respond. It doesn't seem to have been mentioned on the main meta.stackoverflow site; is it just an issue for here, or is it global to SE?

Comment: @JonW: The styles seem to belong to the base stylesheet (they're applied at Stack Overflow too), but they look right in context there because of the much larger font they use for vote scores.

Comment: can how provide a link to how you got the screenshots above?

Comment: @Jin: [Here you go](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/11687/kit-grose?tab=answers&sort=votes) (it happens on [your profile](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/4/jin?tab=answers&sort=votes) too). The second screenshot comes from me removing the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` declarations in Safari's Inspector window.

Comment: @KitGrose got it. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have put in a fix for this, it will be on live server after the next production build.

Comment: This is not fixed in the current site; has the new build not gone live yet? Looks like it might be fixed on the "summary" page but not the "answers" page?

Comment: Just a note that this is still not correct in production.